# 3 Options on IF function

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have ran into and issue of trying to create a function capable of measuring in between a varying range with 3 different answers.

- A "Y" if it's in the range.
- A *"space"* if there is no value stated.
- A "N" if it falls outside of the range

The formula currently being used is simply giving an answer as "Y" if it between the 2 results and a "N" if it does not. The formula is stated below.

```
=IF((D20>=R7)*(D20<=U7),"Y","N")
```

The formula does function in working out if the cell falls between the two ranges, however it does not account for empty cells and labels them as being 'false'. Which is not exactly what I need for a final calculation at the end, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try follownig formula

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(D20),ISBLANK(R7),ISBLANK(U7)),"",IF((D20>=R7)*(D20<=U7),"Y","N"))
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks for the help and the fast reply